# Pivot One Column and Retain SUM,AVG,COUNT Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Let's say I have a table PRODUCT like this.

```
ProductName    Amount
---------------------
Soap           1.10
Toothbrush     2.00
Towel          3.00
Soap           3.00
```

Then I get their sum, average and count using group by.

```
SELECT 
    [ProductName],
    SUM([Amount]) AS 'Sum', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
    AVG([Amount]) AS 'Avg'
FROM Product
GROUP BY [ProductIdName]
```

I have this result.

```
ProductName  Sum  Count  Avg
-----------------------------
Soap         4.10     2  2.05 
Toothbrush   2.00     1  2.00 
Towel        3.00     1  3.00
```

I want to pivot the productname column into something like this.

```
Type               Soap  Toothbrush  Towel
------------------------------------------
Products Sum       4.10        2.00   3.00 
Products Count        2           1      1
Products Average   2.05        2.00   3.00
```

I have used pivot to each aggregate then union all, which I think is too verbose and not efficient? So I'm thinking if there are other solutions for this.

```
    SELECT 
        'Products Sum' AS [Type],
        *
    FROM Product t
    PIVOT(
        SUM(Amount)     
        FOR [ProductName] IN (
            [Soap], 
            [Toothbrush], 
            [Towel]
        )
    ) AS pivot_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'Products Count' AS [Type],
        *
    FROM Product t
    PIVOT(
        COUNT(Amount)       
        FOR [ProductName] IN (
            [Soap], 
            [Toothbrush], 
            [Towel]
        )
    ) AS pivot_table
    ...etc ( pivot AVG(Amount) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using both `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT 
        'Products ' + col as [Type], [Soap], [Toothbrush], [Towel]
from
(SELECT 
    ProductName,
    CONVERT(sql_variant, SUM([Amount])) AS 'Sum', 
    CONVERT(sql_variant, COUNT(*)) AS 'Count',
    CONVERT(sql_variant, AVG([Amount])) AS 'Avg'
FROM Product
GROUP BY ProductName
)t
unpivot
(
    val for col in ([sum], [count], [avg])
)upvt
pivot
(
    max(val) for ProductName in ([Soap], [Toothbrush], [Towel])
)pvt
```

Please see the demo [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a732f786feafc07465734805d558bc2).

Comment: Wow. Thanks! This looks really clean. Performance wise, are there significant difference between this and the pivot union all, or is it negligible?

Comment: @eyese7en I checked the statistics for both approaches (within SQL Server) and don't see a definite performance gain of one approach over another. You can accept the answer (by clicking on the 'right' icon beside the answer) so that others can easily see that the question is answered and the problem is solved.